# Formatting a winform flexgrid cellrange style, conditional base

Tags: c#, css, winforms

I have a winform flexgrid, where certain columns I would like to apply conditional base style.

Like, column index 4 to 8 are numeric columns where I want to show positive numbers in green and and negative numbers in red.

I'm not interested with OwnerDrawCell event, since it is doing Cell by cell (performance issue).

Is is possible to do conditional formatting at column level or setting cellrange style based on its value.

Many Thanks!